# Calculating a variance

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

I want to calculate a variance of an estimator $Z$. $Z$ is the derivative of another estimator $Y$ with respect to some parameter $\theta$. I have the variance of $Y$ and now want to compute the variance of $Z$. My reference is a thesis so I don't know whether it's a mistake or some method I am not aware of. To compute the variance of $Z$ they assume that $\xi$ is $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distributed and write $$Y = \mathbb E[Y] + \xi\sqrt{\mathbb V[Y]}$$
and then take the derivative with respect the parameter $\theta$ to get the variance of $Z$, i.e.
$$Z = \frac{\partial Y}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial\mathbb E[Y]}{\partial\theta} + \xi\frac{\partial\left(\sqrt{\mathbb V[Y]}\right)}{\partial\theta}.$$
They conclude that the variance of $Z$ is given by $\left(\frac{\partial\left(\sqrt{\mathbb V[Y]}\right)}{\partial\theta}\right)^2$. Why? It should be noted that there is no assumption about the distribution of $Y$ made neither.

Comment: This looks like the Delta Method.  Google that term.

Comment: I know the Delta Method but I am pretty certain it is not used here (and if yes it is not correct – unless I am missing a major point here). First, since the Delta method requires a distribution and does not specify one (where does $\xi\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ come from?). Second, the Delta method requires a sufficiently smooth function. The differential operator is not smooth though.

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot differentiate an estimator with respect to a parameter. You can differentiate the expectation or the variance, but not the estimator itself. Have you represented completely what problem the thesis is trying to solve? Because the formula given in your question don't entirely make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can find the full problem here http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/ml2010/CMU-ML-10-112.pdf 3.8.2.4 (proof of lemma 3.4) because I don't see why it should not be possible to differentiate an estimator wrt to a parameter (in the thesis it is the kde wrt to the bandwidth) – as long as the derivative is measurable it satisfies the definition of an estimator.

Comment: OK, thanks, the link to the thesis explains all. Syd, your question as written above is far too obscure for anyone to answer. You need to give the thesis URL as part of your question and you need to explain what it is you don't understand *in the context of the thesis*. How else would we know what $\zeta$ is supposed to be? Trying to re-express it as an abstract question about differentiation of random variables doesn't help. It will take a lot of time for anyone to read the thesis and explain it to you, but perhaps there will be a taker.

Comment: In mathematical statistics, the term "parameter" refers to distribution characteristics and the use of Greek letters like $\theta$ is reserved for unknown population parameters that you are trying to estimate. You obviously can't differentiation a random variable with respect to an unknown parameter. On the other hand, you can differentiate estimators with respect to known quantities used to compute them. So, yes, certainly you can differentiate a kernal estimator with respect to the bandwidth. But don't use Greek letters for bandwith -- it will confuse statisticians on this forum.

Comment: that's true, I haven't thought about possible confusion by using the term "parameter". I edited the question. However, I don't think the context is relevant here as there are no assumptions made about the kernel in the quoted lemma. So either they assume a normal distribution or there exists some theorem that does what I asked in my question without postulating a distribution. I just wondered whether the latter could be the case.

Comment: The manipulations here are plausible but they look fundamentally mistaken to me, because they assume $\xi$ does not depend on $\theta$ -- but there's no reason in general to suppose that.